# Inner Join Update Statement command not properly ended

Tags: sql, oracle

The following update statement is my first attempt of using an inner join on an update statement. I have the syntax wrong but I am not sure where but I keep getting command not properly ended error. Can anyone help with this.

```
UPDATE m_rqgrechunk a
SET    a.persondept = b.persondept
FROM   m_rqgrechunk a
       INNER JOIN m_person_persondept_hist b
         ON a.person = b.person
WHERE  ( ( b.from_date IS NULL
           AND b.to_date IS NULL )
          OR ( b.from_date IS NULL
               AND a.create_date < b.to_date )
          OR ( a.create_date >= b.from_date
               AND a.create_date < b.to_date )
          OR ( a.create_date >= b.from_date
               AND a.to_date IS NULL ) )
       AND a.persondept IS NULL
```

Comment: Based on "command not properly ended" I have assumed Oracle.

Comment: @Ryan - This is valid in TSQL's proprietary `UPDATE ... FROM` syntax. But based on the error message they don't seem to be using SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

This is how it can be done in Oracle:

```
UPDATE m_rqgrechunk a
SET    a.persondept = 
       ( SELECT b.persondept
         FROM m_person_persondept_hist b
         WHERE a.person = b.person
           AND ( ( b.from_date IS NULL
                   AND b.to_date IS NULL )
              OR ( b.from_date IS NULL
                   AND a.create_date < b.to_date )
              OR ( a.create_date >= b.from_date
                   AND a.create_date < b.to_date )
              OR ( a.create_date >= b.from_date
                   AND a.to_date IS NULL ) )
       )
WHERE a.persondept IS NULL 
  AND EXISTS 
       ( SELECT 1  
         FROM m_person_persondept_hist b 
         WHERE a.person = b.person  
           AND ( ( b.from_date IS NULL 
                   AND b.to_date IS NULL ) 
              OR ( b.from_date IS NULL  
                   AND a.create_date < b.to_date ) 
              OR ( a.create_date >= b.from_date 
                   AND a.create_date < b.to_date )
              OR ( a.create_date >= b.from_date
                   AND a.to_date IS NULL ) )
       ) ;
```

The `NOT EXISTS` part is not really needed in this case because the values to be updated are `NULL` so it doesn't hurt (much) to voidly update them with `NULL`, except for logging space which gets bloated without reason.

---

Another way is to use a derived table:

```
UPDATE 
( SELECT a.persondept, b.persondept AS persondept_new
  FROM m_rqgrechunk a
    JOIN m_person_persondept_hist b
      ON a.person = b.person
  WHERE ( ( b.from_date IS NULL
            AND b.to_date IS NULL )
       OR ( b.from_date IS NULL
            AND a.create_date < b.to_date )
       OR ( a.create_date >= b.from_date
            AND a.create_date < b.to_date )
       OR ( a.create_date >= b.from_date
            AND a.to_date IS NULL ) )
    AND a.persondept IS NULL
) 
SET persondept = persondept_new ;
```

Answer (score 0):

An update with join is IMHO done like this

```
UPDATE m_rqgrechunk a
   INNER JOIN m_person_persondept_hist b
     ON a.person = b.person
SET    a.persondept = b.persondept
WHERE  ( ( b.from_date IS NULL
       AND b.to_date IS NULL )
      OR ( b.from_date IS NULL
           AND a.create_date < b.to_date )
      OR ( a.create_date >= b.from_date
           AND a.create_date < b.to_date )
      OR ( a.create_date >= b.from_date
           AND a.to_date IS NULL ) )
   AND a.persondept IS NULL
```